# Mutual authentication possible flaw

Tags: authentication, cryptography, hash

I am taking this mutual authentication example from Wikipedia:

```
Server sends a unique challenge value sc to the client
Client generates unique challenge value cc
Client computes cr = hash(cc + sc + secret)
Client sends cr and cc to the server
Server calculates the expected value of cr and ensures the client responded correctly
Server computes sr = hash(sc + cc + secret)
Server sends sr
Client calculates the expected value of sr and ensures the server responded correctly
where

sc is the server generated challenge
cc is the client generated challenge
cr is the client response
sr is the server response
```

I am trying to see if there is a possible security issue here. Assuming we are using a strong hash function and AES symmetric key, do you think there exists a security flaw here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think server should authenticate itself first. The problem now is that the client can be fooled to authenticate to a third-party which will in turn actively authenticate to the server, which will complete at server end, even if it fails at client end. The man in the middle could then carry on with actions, even if the client has failed and disconnected for long time ago.

Best way here is to have the sender to send sc, AND hash(sc, hash(secret)) to the client at first step. At second step, before client generates cc, it will check that hash matches the expected value.

By double-hashing the secret, you gain additional security.

Otherwise, the communication goes out as outlined. Then it will be very secure, as the client will refuse to initiate authentication if the server-generated hash doesn't match.